# Data verify errors on DVD after burning

Tags: dvd, burning

I have been using an external HP dvd1035i DVD Writer for burning mostly DVD-Videos for about 2 years using Nero Burning ROM. Today, I had to burn some large data files with their CRC check which I've almost never bothered to verify. It got me wasted about 8 DVD Discs with one or two random bad sector errors until I was finally able to burn perfect copy of data.

Is it about time to change my DVD drive? Why would i have those few sector errors even with minimum burn speed?

I haven't checked to see if it gives any data verify errors with CD burning.

Comment: Is/are the bad sector(s) always in the same place?

Comment: Nope, Everytime at different sectors for different files.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the lens with an optical-drive cleaning disc (a “CD” with a small, soft brush built in).